# Can "not complete" and "incomplete" be used interchangeably?

Tags: word-choice

Can *not complete* and *incomplete* be used interchangeably?

I don't know what else to elaborate more.
Thank you.

EDIT:

> All tasks are incomplete.
>   All tasks are not complete.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. Please give example sentences.

Comment: No two synonyms are entirely "interchangeable".  But those two are, mostly.  A lot depends on the context (which you omitted).

Comment: @Davo I tried to give an example.

Comment: A plural example allows for varying interpretations. **This task is incomplete** and **This task is not complete** have the same meaning. However, **All tasks are incomplete** usually means that each and every task is incomplete, while **All tasks are not complete** usually means that some tasks may be complete, but not all of them are.

Comment: I will post this as an answer, then you can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plural example allows for varying interpretations. **This task is incomplete** and **This task is not complete** have the same meaning.

However, **All tasks are incomplete** usually means that each and every task is incomplete, while **All tasks are not complete** usually means that some tasks may be complete, but not all of them are

Comment: Not sure about this. **Not all tasks are complete** would imply as you said; **all tasks are not complete** seems to me identical to **all tasks are incomplete**.

Comment: This is what I meant with: A plural example allows for varying interpretations - one must consider the audience.

Comment: OK, fair enough.